# How to get the DataType and Size of a column using the SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, .net, database, getschematable

i am trying to get the data type of each column given to do some verification 
i already tried the `getSchemaTable` but it only gives me the schema of a table without values.

For example , i have a table in my database and a columnname : `id_declarant`. 
I want to retrieve the datatype and Size of a value from `id_declarant`.

Here is The code :

```
comm.Connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString);
String sql = @"
            SELECT * 
            FROM id_declarant,declarant
            WHERE (declarant.Nom_pren_RS='" + textBox1.Text + "') 
            and   (id_declarant.mat_fisc=declarant.mat_fisc)  "; 
comm.CommandText = sql;
comm.Connection.Open();
string mat_fisc;
string clé_mat_fisc;
string categorie ;
string num_etab_sec ;
string activite;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String Nom = textBox1.Text;
using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //here i want to know how to retrieve the reader[0].Type and Size to do the verification 
         mat_fisc = reader[0].ToString();
         clé_mat_fisc = reader["clé_mat_fisc"].ToString();
         categorie = reader["categorie"].ToString();
         num_etab_sec = reader["num_etab_sec"].ToString();
         activite = reader["activite"].ToString();
         sb.Append("EF" + mat_fisc + clé_mat_fisc + categorie + num_etab_sec + textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text + Nom + activite);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Type type = reader.GetFieldType(0);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more your answer please ?

Comment: i tried this one : string Type= reader["id_declarant"].GetFieldType(0).FullName; but it displays System.string

Comment: It's Type type = reader.GetFieldType(0); instead of string Type= reader["id_declarant"].GetFieldType(0).FullName; BTW, what is the data type of id_declarant coumn

Comment: yes the reader.GetFieldType(0)   displays the DataType of each value in the row 0 of the reader ?? BTW id_declarant is nvarchar(7)

Comment: reader.GetFieldType(0) displays the first column's .net data type. So the data type of id_declarant in the database coresponds System.String type in C#

Comment: thank you so much you really helped me , and for the max size i didn't find the method definition in the methods of SqlDataReader , have you any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Please use function GetTableSchema .

```
SqlDataReader reader= command.ExecuteReader();

using (var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable())
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            string ColumnName= row.Field<string>("ColumnName");
            string DataTypeName= row.Field<string>("DataTypeName");
            short NumericPrecision= row.Field<short>("NumericPrecision");
            short NumericScale= row.Field<short>("NumericScale");
            int ColumnSize= row.Field<int>("ColumnSize");
            Console.WriteLine("Column: {0} Type: {1} Precision: {2} Scale: {3} ColumnSize {4}",      
            ColumnName, DataTypeName, NumericPrecision, NumericScale, ColumnSize);
        }
    }
```

Using Table schema , you can get all column related property using c# .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetDataTypeName() function to get the data type of the field

```
   String dataType = reader.GetDataTypeName(FIELD_INDEX);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string ReadString(IDataReader reader, string columnName) {

string myString = "";

var index = reader.GetOrdinal(columnName);

var fieldType = reader.GetFieldType(index);

if (fieldType.FullName.Contains("Guid"))
{
myString = reader.IsDBNull(index) ? "" : reader.GetGuid(index).ToString();
}
else
{
myString = reader.IsDBNull(index) ? "" : reader.GetString(index);
}
return myString;
}
```